# Laravel LeftJoin return duplicate value from first column (mysql)

Tags: mysql, laravel, left-join

Column workers:
[image]

Column recommendations:
[image]

My query:

```
$getRecommendationWorker = Worker::select('workers.id', 'workers.name', 'workers.photo', 'workers.description', 'workers.profile_worker', 'recommendations.recommendation', 'recommendations.author', 'recommendations.work_author', 'recommendations.profile_author')
->leftJoin('recommendations', 'workers.id', '=', 'recommendations.worker_id')
->get();
```

Laravel return:

```
{"id":5,"name":"Piotr Debowski","photo":"3c29641e2a.jpeg","description":"sdasdasd","profile_worker":"https:\/\/codepen.io\/","recommendation":"pierwsza rekomendacja","author":"Jan Kowalski","work_author":"IT spec","profile_author":"https:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/43136250\/eloquent-join-table-with-two-conditions"}
{"id":5,"name":"Piotr Debowski","photo":"3c29641e2a.jpeg","description":"sdasdasd","profile_worker":"https:\/\/codepen.io\/","recommendation":"druga rekomendacja","author":"Jan Wo\u017aniak","work_author":"dsad","profile_author":"https:\/\/nczas.com\/2018\/08\/21\/wreszcie-zatrzymali-t"}
```

I have the `id`,`name` and other value from table `workers` twice returned.
I want return look like this:

```
{"id":5,"name":"Piotr Debowski","photo":"3c29641e2a.jpeg","description":"sdasdasd","profile_worker":"https:\/\/codepen.io\/","recommendation":"pierwsza rekomendacja","author":"Jan Kowalski","work_author":"IT spec","profile_author":"https:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/43136250\/eloquent-join-table-with-two-conditions","recommendation":"druga rekomendacja","author":"Jan Wo\u017aniak","work_author":"dsad","profile_author":"https:\/\/nczas.com\/2018\/08\/21\/wreszcie-zatrzymali-t"}
```

I want from table `workers` return only one row and from table `recommendations` all records related to the first table.
When I use `groupBy` (for example: `...->->groupBy('workers.id')`) return me only frst record from table `recommendations`. I can't use `where`, because all values will be displayed on the same page.
Column `worker_id` is related to table `workers`

**EDIT:**

Worker model:

```
public function recommendations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Recommendation');
}
```

Recommendation model:

```
public function workers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Worker');
}
```

Comment: That's how a join works.  `When I use groupBy, return me only frst record from table recommendations`... isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Devon No from table `recommendations` i want get all record related to table `workers` Why give me minus, what is wrong in my query !!

Comment: yeah, but you have multiple recommendations for a single worker, which is why you need to group them...

Comment: @Devon Whe I use `->groupBy('recommendations.worker_id')` Laravel return only ONE RECORD FROM TABLE `recommendations` BUT I WANT RETURN ALL RECORDS FROM `recommendations` TABLE, WHICH ARE RELATED TO TABLE `workers`

Comment: That really shouldn't be the case if you have different values of recommendations.worker_id.  Dump out the SQL of your query (either using debug bar or `toSql()`)

Comment: Ok.. I see what you mean, your question just isn't well formatted.  You have two recommendations in your desired output, but it's not easy to tell.  Left Join isn't what you want, use Eloquent's relationships...

Comment: @Devon I have Eloquent's relationships. I edit my query.

Comment: Go through the docs and read how to use those relationships then.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, can you show how you're using this in your blade file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to [load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the `recommendations` relationship:

```
$workers = Worker::with('recommendations')->get();
```

and then access the recommendations by looping through them e.g.

```
@foreach($workers as $worker)

    @foreach($worker->recommendations as $recommendation)

        //

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

However, if you want the rows to be formatted like the example in your question then you can take advantage of the fact they're [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections):

```
$workers = Worker::with('recommendations')->get()
    ->flatMap(function ($worker) {

        $recommendations = $worker->recommendations->isEmpty()
            ? collect([new \App\Recommendation])
            : $worker->recommendations;

        return $recommendations->map(function ($recommendation) use ($worker) {
            return (object)[
                'id'             => $worker->id,
                'name'           => $worker->name,
                'photo'          => $worker->photo,
                'description'    => $worker->description,
                'profile_worker' => $worker->profile_worker,
                'recommendation' => $recommendation->recommendation,
                'author'         => $recommendation->author,
                'work_author'    => $recommendation->work_author,
                'profile_author' => $recommendation->profile_author,
            ];
        });
    });
```